# Calculating offset and zoom in a graph after a mouse wheel scroll

Tags: java, math, graph

I am currently working on a project in Java where I need to implement a draggable and zoomable graph.

The current implementation involves a graph object having an array of predefined points to draw. And whenever the graph wants to draw a point to the screen, it asks a "graph transformer" to apply affine transformations to the point to get its location on the screen.

The graph transformer contains an X and Y offset as well as a zoom. So basically, a point P will be transformed as follows :

```
P_x = zoom_x * P_x + offset_x
P_y = zoom_y * P_y + offset_y
```

The offset is updated when the user drags the graph and the zoom is updated when the user scrolls the mouse wheel.

Everything is working just as intended. The thing is that the zoom is always applied relative to the origin (0,0) of the graph, which is normal. But what I would like to do is apply the zoom relative to the mouse position.

I've been scratching my head for quite some time now, and I am getting a bit confused between the real coordinates and the transformed coordinates.

How could I implement this feature without modifying too much my code ?

Here are my Java methods :

The method transforming points :

```java
public Point transform(Point p) {
    Point transformed = new Point();
    transformed.x = Math.round(Math.round((m_zoom.x * p.x) + m_offset.x));
    transformed.y = Math.round(Math.round((m_zoom.y * p.y) + m_offset.y));
    return transformed;
}
```

The methods called when mouse events are fired :

```java
@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    m_pressed = e.getPoint();
    m_lastCalculatedOffset.x = 0;
    m_lastCalculatedOffset.y = 0;
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    Point zoomedDragging = new Point();
    zoomedDragging.x = Math.round(Math.round(e.getX() - m_pressed.x));
    zoomedDragging.y = Math.round(Math.round(e.getY() - m_pressed.y));

    m_offset.x += zoomedDragging.x - m_lastCalculatedOffset.x;
    m_offset.y += zoomedDragging.y - m_lastCalculatedOffset.y;

    m_lastCalculatedOffset.x = zoomedDragging.x;
    m_lastCalculatedOffset.y = zoomedDragging.y;
}

@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    m_zoom.x *= Math.pow(ZOOM_FACTOR, e.getWheelRotation());
    m_zoom.y *= Math.pow(ZOOM_FACTOR, e.getWheelRotation());
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after taking a break and drawing the problem on paper user graph examples, I managed to find a solution :

If we call ZoomP the location of the mouse when the zoom occurs, once the zoom has been done, the following transformation has to be done to the offset :

```
newOffset_x = oldOffset_x + (1 - (newZoom_x / oldZoom_x)) * (ZoomP_x - oldOffset_x)
newOffset_y = oldOffset_y + (1 - (newZoom_y / oldZoom_y)) * (ZoomP_y - oldOffset_y)
```

So here is my updated mouseWheelMoved method for those interested :

```java
@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
    Point mousePos = e.getPoint();

    Point2D.Double newZoom = new Point2D.Double();
    newZoom.x = m_zoom.x * Math.pow(ZOOM_FACTOR, e.getWheelRotation());
    newZoom.y = m_zoom.y * Math.pow(ZOOM_FACTOR, e.getWheelRotation());

    m_offset.x += Math.round(Math.round((1 - (newZoom.x / m_zoom.x)) * (mousePos.x - m_offset.x)));
    m_offset.y += Math.round(Math.round((1 - (newZoom.y / m_zoom.y)) * (mousePos.y - m_offset.y)));

    m_zoom = newZoom;
}
```